# Removing rows between two ID-values in panel data set

Tags: r, subset, panel

I have a panel data set with the following columns: "ID", "Year", "Poverty rate", "Health services".

I have data from 2011-2013, and the table is ordered after the value of ID, looking something like this:

```
merged_data_frame = structure(list(ID = c(1001,1001,1001,2001,2001,2001,2002,2002,2002,2003,2003,2003,3001,3001,3001), 
               Year = c(2011,2012,2013,2011,2012,2013,2011,2012,2013,2011,2012,2013,2011,2012,2013),
               Poverty_rate = c(0.5,0.4,0.3,0.45,0.1,0.35,0.55,0.55,0.55,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.1,0.11,0.1 )), row.names = c(1:15), class = "data.frame")
```

How do I remove the values for the rows with ID between 2001 and 2003? My actual dataset have more than 5000 values, so I need something that removes everything between 2001 and 2xxx.

I managed to remove one and one value, but that is not an option given the size of the data set:

```
new_data_frame<-subset(merged_data_frame, merged_data_frame$ID!=20013)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using `filter(!ID %in% c(2001,2003)`

```
merged_data_frame = structure(list(ID = c(1001,1001,1001,2001,2001,2001,2002,2002,2002,2003,2003,2003,3001,3001,3001), 
               Year = c(2011,2012,2013,2011,2012,2013,2011,2012,2013,2011,2012,2013,2011,2012,2013),
               Poverty_rate = c(0.5,0.4,0.3,0.45,0.1,0.35,0.55,0.55,0.55,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.1,0.11,0.1 )), row.names = c(1:15), class = "data.frame")

df = merged_data_frame %>% 
  filter(!ID %in% c(2001,2003))
```